# Can you connect iPhone/iPad to Apple TV without WiFi network in place

Tags: iphone, ipad, wifi, bluetooth, appletv

I would like to make a presentation from an iPhone or iPad using an AppleTV and projector. Is it possible to do so without either a WiFi or LAN network in place (like in a bad hotel)? Is the AppleTV able to act as a WiFi/Bluetooth access point so that iDevice can connect to it and show the presentation? Or is that not possible?

Are there any workarounds for this, or do I have to bring wireless router with me as well?

Comment: Just added an answer to your question... see the last post in the list. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, nice addition. I didn't thought of that. If that really works then great :-)

Comment: Try to change the answer since it's now possible.

Comment: You have to set up a WiFi network.  The bandwith requried for video far outstips the available bandwidth in bluetooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can with a 3G + Data Plan iPad 2 / iPhone and above.

Create a Personal Hotspot wifi with a certain name and password.

Have the Apple TV connect to it.

Now take you Apple TV anywhere with you. 
To setup an airplay/projector broadcast.
Start the Personal Hotspot wifi.
Connect the Apple TV to any hdmi projector.

Done. You can airplay your keynote or video to the projector.

NEXT...

This will work with any AirPlay enabled app. Using Keynote with AirPlay is no different.

Tap Keynote to launch it on the iPad, and then open the presentation you want to give.

Double tap the Home button on the iPad itself, and the multitasking bar will appear at the bottom of the screen.

Swipe to the right to reveal the media bar, which has the AirPlay button just to the left of the Volume slider.

Tap the AirPlay button and select Apple TV, then tap the Mirroring switch to turn that on. The TV screen should now have your presentation on it, ready to go.

You can also use this method to send the signal from any AirPlay enabled app video-out to an AppleTV.

Enjoy a "walk around, ipad in hand" wireless presentation.

PS. There are also some older VGA projectors, for those you might need an hdmi to vga "active" converter cable to hook the apple tv to it. Haven't tested this, and that cable is around 40-50$.

Comment: @tcdaly You need a data plan on the device creating the personal hotspot, if you have a phone use that and connect both your wifi ipad and apple tv to that.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot connect directly to the Apple TV, so you will have to bring a router.

Comment: An Apple AirPort Express would be good for this purpose. You can find an earlier model in used condition for less money. http://store.apple.com/us/product/FB321LL/A

Answer (score 2):

If you have a laptop, you could set it up as a DHCP server, and run an Ethernet cable from the laptop to the Apple TV.  Theoretically.

Comment: Having a laptop he can just create an ad-hoc network and connect both to it.