# Streaming local content from iPhone to Apple TV without WiFi or data connection

Tags: appletv, airplay

I'm going on a trip abroad - where I will not have a data plan - to a place where there is no wifi. There is a TV, however, and I was thinking of bringing my 3rd gen Apple TV to be able to watch some media on the screen. The plan is to create a local hotspot on the phone; let the Apple TV connect to it and then use Airplay to play already downloaded content from my phone.

Will this work? I can't test it without the data plan without leaving the country.

[This post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54141/can-you-connect-iphone-ipad-to-apple-tv-without-wifi-network-in-place) discusses a similar issue, but they seem to have a working data connection.

Comment: You don't need to leave the country to test this. 
Turn off data on your phone and then see if hotspot works?

Comment: Good point. If I turn off data, I can't create a hotspot(the button is disabled). I won't turn off data on my vacation, though, I will just disable roaming, so my phone might still think it has a data connection.

Comment: It may be easier for you to buy a cheap wireless router with you - or maybe take your current wireless router with you

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It works. As long as you can turn on a local hotspot on the phone, you can let the Apple TV connect to it and use AirPlay to stream content from the phone to the TV. Furthermore my friend could connect his iPad to the hotspot and stream video from his device to the TV.

Comment: Please refrain from adding comments in the Answer section, this is for answers to the questions. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you’ll be able to add [comments](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and ask follow-up questions. To gain reputation, [answer questions that are clear and concise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: I'm sorry, I could have been clearer. I'm the OP and I tried it and it works. So it's an answer, not a comment.

Comment: I understand, according the Help Center, it's preferred that questions and answers be 'self-contained'.  This helps others with searching (as well as people who get to this site from search engines indexing the answers).

Answer (score 1):

Yes this works! 
You must switch on Bluetooth on both devices. 
Afterwards go to the Control Center and check if AirPlay is diplayed. When the AirPlay Button don't show up you might restart and try it again. When it's working you have to turn on 'Mirror'. That's it.

Comment: Ok, but won't I be using the Bluetooth connection then? That won't be fast enough to stream 1080p  movies, will it?

Comment: @bgp2000: You have to try it. When you want to watch this 1080p movie a Lightning adapter would be better.